# Flutter IOS Architecture Issue in M1 Mac using VS code

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, apple-m1

I am using an M1 MacBook pro laptop and ios 13 simulator for developing a flutter app, But I am getting the below issue while trying to run the flutter app in the emulator.

This started happening when I upgraded my workspace to Flutter 2.8.
No problem while running in Android.

Please advise how to resolve this issue.

Kindly do not advise me to do the development in Xcode. I am not familiar and do not have enough bandwidth to learn new IDE. I am using VSCODE.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
Xcode build done.                                            1.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/path/to/flutter/project/projectname/ios/Runner.xcodeproj: error: The linked framework 'Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64. 
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited (sigterm)
```

[image: (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')]

Comment: The warning you can fix opening the iOS folder in Xcode, select the Runner on targets > Signing & capabilities and select a team or personal account. The problem with Architectures i'm facing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Specify one more architecture for m1 chip.

### `Runner > Build Settings > Excluded Architecture > Add arm64`

This solution worked for me.

[image]